# Changing integer values in NSMutableArray, IOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays, xcode

I created an array that would hold some integers. However I seem to get an error on a line of code which is trying to alter one of the values in the array. I have created an array as follows:

```
NSMutableArray *lockedArray;
lockedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:50];
```

I have added some values into the array:

```
[lockedArray addObject:@10];
[lockedArray addObject:@20];
[lockedArray addObject:@30];
[lockedArray addObject:@40];
[lockedArray addObject:@50];
[lockedArray addObject:@60];
[lockedArray addObject:@70];
[lockedArray addObject:@80];
```

Now I want to change one of the values. For example if I want to change the 6th value then I use the following code...

```
[lockedArray replaceObjectAtIndex:5 withObject:@1];
```

In Xcode I do not get any warning and it all looks fine. When I run the code and initiate replacing an object it crashes and gives me the following error...

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray
>   replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: mutating method sent to immutable
>   object'

Comment: The problem is the way, you are creating your array. Your array is immutable. Probably the array come from a dictionary, webService or something like that. In some part of your code, you have: lockedArray = somethingThanIsAndArray; Change to this: lockedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:somethingThanIsAndArray];

Comment: How do you create the actual array that you assign to the `lockedArray` pointer?  Do you ever change what `lockedArray` points to?

Comment: @PhillipMills I have added the code in an edit

Comment: I think the exception is clear. Your lockedArray isn't a mutableArray. (Post all your code), or make a NSLog(@"%@",[[lockedArray class] description]);

Comment: It has to be related to something that happens between the time you populate the array and the time you do the replace.  If I simply run your code as a sequence of statements (declare, assign, populate, replace), it works as expected with no error.

Comment: better to post the entire method

Comment: Voting to leave this open- please heed the @PhillipMills comment: the array  must -- at some point -- be getting replaced with an immutable array.  Look at every assignment to that variable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have u allocated and initialized ur array like this,

```
lockedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Try it, Hope it will work for u

Comment: This may not solve the problem, probable in the assignment, He point the pointer "lockedArray" to other array.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know what you are doing exactly, but at the point where replaceObjectAtIndex is called, lockedArray is not a mutable array but an immutable array.

Since an array cannot be changed from being mutable to immutable, you most likely assigned a different (immutable) array to lockedArray after you added the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check that you haven't pointed lockedArray to a non mutable array or you haven't initiated it as such. Use Xcode's find function to search for

> "lockedArray = [NSArray"

or

> "lockedArray ="